Redis Sentinel: The ConnectionMultiplexer is not a Sentinel connection. Detected as: Standalone Error
Our project is a .NET 8 API project, and we are using Redis version 2.8.0 as a caching mechanism. However, we are randomly encountering an error that shows "Sentinel: The ConnectionMultiplexer is not a Sentinel connection. Detected as: Standalone," and sometimes we don't receive this error. I haven't been able to identify the cause of this issue. What steps should I follow to resolve this error?
I am sharing our codes
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.8.0" />
 var redisConfigurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions()
                {
                    EndPoints = { { redisConfiguration.SentinelUrl!, redisConfiguration.Port } },
                    Password = redisConfiguration.Password,
                    ServiceName = redisConfiguration.ServiceName,
                    AbortOnConnectFail = redisConfiguration.AbortOnConnectFail, 
                    ConnectRetry = redisConfiguration.ConnectRetry, 
                    ConnectTimeout = redisConfiguration.ConnectTimeout, 
                    ReconnectRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(redisConfiguration.ReconnectRetry) 
                
                };
var redisClient = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConfigurationOptions)

And  redisConfiguration.SentinelUrl = redissentineltest.ourproject.com
redisConfiguration.Port = 26397
